# for what "../.." used for? I found it today in this line var express = require('../..');

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Hey I was trying to understand node-js routes and found this sentence "var express = require('../..');"
I don't understand the meaning/usage of '../..' here please can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It means importing the index file from that location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'../..' is a relative path to index.js file which is situated two folders behind.

Let's say hypothetically your folder structure looks like this -

```
folder1
  - index.js
  - folder2
      - folder3
          - your-code.js
```

and your-code.js looks like this,

```
const express = require('../..');
```

will mean to import the JS module from 'index.js' file in `folder1`